# Many to Many with attribute and two checkbox lists in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have two entity, User and Language, with a relation many to many with attributes between them. I want to make a form with two checkbox list showing the same values, but the first list give the value "good" to the extra attribute, and the second list give "bad".

Is it possible to do this with the form builder of Symfony?

My User class:

```
class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Lift\TalentBundle\Entity\UserLanguage",    mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $languages;
```

My language class:

```
class Language
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

My relation class between them:

class UserLanguage {

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="integer")
 */
private $level;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lift\TalentBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="languages")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lift\TalentBundle\Entity\Language")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $language;
```

$level have int value (1 for good and 2 for bad)

And I try to create the form like this:

```
$builder->add('languages','entity',[
                'class' =>'LiftTalentBundle:UserLanguage',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ])
        ;
```

But it doesn't not work, and i have no idea how to build two list which auto assign the $level value in my UserLanguage table

Comment: post your code (related to the question).

Comment: done, tell me if you need more or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution here:
http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/07/symfnoy2-many-to-many-relation-with.html

With new functions in the User entity I can build my 2 list as I want